# li $a0, 0x09? MIPS

Tags: mips

What is this code doing? Please help.

```
li $a0, 0x09
li $v0, 11
syscall
```

I know system call 11 is print char but what im not sure of is the load immmediate. Is it just loading 9 into `$a0`?

- *

Comment: `Is it just loading 9 into $a0 ?`, yes

Answer (score 0):

$a0 contains the argument for the syscall, thus maybe the character to print.
Here I say 'maybe' because I am not sure syscall 11 is printing a char...

Here are the references:
1.http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/System_Instructions
2.http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm